# python xlsx to csv with records of variable length

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

```
#example 1
from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv

Xlsx2csv("C:\CS\Archiv-Fix_csv_.xlsx", outputencoding="utf-8").convert("C:\CS\name.csv")

#example 2
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_excel (r'C:\CS\Fix_csv_.xlsx', sheet_name='Patch')
read_file.to_csv (r'C:\CS\name.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

This works as expected but my problem is to handle records of variable length.

> Lets say my first row is filled filled up to column P, row 98 up to K and
> row 2980 up to M and so on.

So what I get is a csv file with delimiters to fill every row up to column P:

> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,K,L,M,N,O,P
>
> A,,C,,E,F,G,K,,,,,
>
> A,B,C,D,E,,,K,,M,,,

What I need is:

> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,K,L,M,N,O,P
>
> A,,C,,E,F,G,K
>
> A,B,C,D,E,,,K,,M

Hope you can held me out
Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: So you just want to remove the trailing commas from your csv file?  It's simple to do with a loop, but will make the csv file invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for example 2 is that the data frame returned by read_excel must have all rows filled.  The pandas library is inserting nan values to do that.  Unfortunately, the to_csv function does not have an option to skip trailing nan fields.  Hence, you have to do that yourself by iterating over the rows in the data frame like so:

```
import csv
import math
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_excel ('demo.xlsx', header=None, sheet_name='Sheet1')
with open('demo.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
  writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
  for row in read_file.iterrows():
    last=0
    # this loop can be optimized by iterating backwards for first non nan
    for idx,i in enumerate(row[1]):
      if not isinstance(i, float) or not math.isnan(i): last=idx+1
    writer.writerow(row[1][0:last])
```

Maybe there is a nicer solution with xlsx2csv but I am not familiar with that package.